# Who is the artist for Misty's goodbye song during the flashback at "Gotta Catch Ya Later"?

Tags: music, pokemon

I recently rewatched [Pokémon episode 273 - *Gotta Catch Ya Later!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP273), and was wondering about the vocalist behind Misty's goodbye song during the flashback; I can't seem to find the name of the artist anywhere.

**Note**: This is exclusive to the dubbed version. The original Japanese version uses unreleased background music from the movie *The Power of One*.

Comment: I believe that song is from Pokemon Other Songs ME - Y album. Maybe it is listed on there ;)

Comment: Guess I remembered incorrectly. [It is said to be the only un-named song](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/User:Yash_Sen/Misty's_Goodbye_%28song%29)

Answer (score 1):

It's unofficially called 'Misty's Goodbye'. It's an unreleased song, it was played only in that flashback and it was never given an official name. There are no details about the vocalist and there is no full version of the song.